# Django URLConf not matching valid regex

Tags: python, regex, django

I am having a big problem with Django urlconf.  I can't get the regex to match
in urls.py.

Here is what I am doing:

In my javascript I have

```
var source = 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/quiltmaker/block'+i+'/shoefly'+i+'/';
```

which logs as

```
img.src http://127.0.0.1:8000/quiltmaker/block3/shoefly3/
```

my urlpatterns are:

```
   urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^$', views.index, name='index'),
    url(r'^about/$', views.about, name='about'),
    url(r'block(\d{1,3})/([a-z]{7})(\d{1,2})/$', views.block),
)
```

The regex works in the iPython interpreter:

```
js = 'block3/shoefly3/'

r = re.compile(r'block(\d{1,3})/([a-z]{7})(\d{1,2})/$')

r
Out[60]: re.compile(r'block(\d{1,3})/([a-z]{7})(\d{1,2})/$')

m = r.search(js)

m
Out[62]: <_sre.SRE_Match at 0x10f262ae0>

m.span()
Out[63]: (0, 16)
```

BUT Django never calls the view.

It does work if the urlpattern is

```
url(r'block(\d{1,3})/shoefly(\d{1,2})/$', views.block)
```

Please help.  This is driving me crazier than I already am.

Comment: Try to add `^` at the start.

Comment: What arguments does `views.block` expect? Does it work if you don't use a group for the `[a-z]{7}` part, eg `/[a-z]{7}(\d{1,2})/$`?

Comment: I tried adding a ^ at the start.  Still no dice.  But thanks for noticing that I left that out.

Comment: Thanks, Peter.  Removing the group worked but I need the group to pass a parameter to the view.

Comment: Well, the reason I asked is that it looks like your view is expecting exactly two arguments. With three groups it captures more than the view expects.

Comment: You are brilliant.  I should have seen that myself.  Adding another parameter to the view did the trick!!

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to Peter DeGlopper for pointing me in the right direction.  The urlconf didn't send me to the view because the view was expecting two parameters and I was sending three.  Adding another parmeeter to the view did the trick:

Before

```
def block(request, idx, blockno)
```

After

```
def block(request, idx, type, blockno)
```